# String surronded by single quotation mark

Tags: vb.net

so I have this check combo box data source from SQL Server
Let's say I have these string value from the combo box

`ABC, DEF, GHI`

What I wanted next is get those string
and make them become like this
`'ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI'`

I've tried combining them with `"'" & comboBox.Text & "'"`
but it looks like this
`'ABC, DEF, GHI'`

Comment: You should read the documentation for the `String.Split`, `String.Trim` and `String.Join` methods. Maybe read the documentation for the `String` class in general and see what it offers for manipulating strings.

Comment: Thank you for the comment John! I've tried it, but I got confused in the Join part, because I loop through my comboBox to get the String. From the loop the string are surronded correctly already, but I'm stuck with how to join them as a joined single String

Comment: No, you're not confused about the Join part. You're confused about the Split part. If you don't split that example string into three separate parts then there's nothing to join. Try thinking about the logic first, before you try writing code to implement that logic.

Comment: Ok, so I split them, they are in an array now. I looped the array to add the single quotation mark to each of them and now the join part is I don't quite get it

Comment: Ok, I got the join now. Thank you John!

Comment: It's my preference to push people to think for themselves as much as possible and it appears that you did that and got to a solution, so good on you for that. I'll now post an answer that might clean up some rough edges on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're starting with a delimited string and you want to process each substring separately, so that means splitting, processing and joining the string. There are a number of variations on a theme that will do that. Here are a couple of examples:

```vb
Dim substrings = comboBox.Text.Split(","c)

For i = 0 To substrings.getUpperBound(0)
    substrings(i) = "'" & substrings(i).Trim() & "'"
Next

Dim result = String.Join(", ", substrings)
```

```vb
Dim result = String.Join(", ",
                         comboBox.Text.
                                  Split(","c).
                                  Select(Function(s) $"'{s.Trim()}'"))
```

Note that, if you're confident that there will always be a comma and one space between substrings then you can incorporate the space into the `Split` and do away with the `Trim`:

```vb
Dim substrings = comboBox.Text.Split({", "}, StringSplitOptions.None)

For i = 0 To substrings.getUpperBound(0)
    substrings(i) = "'" & substrings(i) & "'"
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do it LINQ style like:

```
 Dim res as string = String.Join(“, “, String.Split(“,”c, original).Select(Function(f) $”’{f.Trim}’”))
```

The process is to split the original into its component parts, remove any white space, add surrounding quotes and combine back into a single string with “, “ as a separator.